# Unexpected end of JSON input using TMDb API

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse JSON data that is returned from The Movie DB. I am getting an error telling me that I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.movieReq.onreadystatechange (discover.js:34)
    at loadIMDBDetails (discover.js:38)
    at MainFunc (discover.js:68)
    at discover.js:5
I am accessing individual movie information using the following XMLHttpRequest:
```

movieReq.open('GET', 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/299537?api_key=', false);

I have other XMLHttpRequests which are returning the JSON data just fine. Those requests are using the discover function of the API.

This is the function which is producing the issue

```
function loadIMDBDetails(mO, i) {
    movieReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    movieReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        var parsedObj = JSON.parse(movieReq.responseText);
        mO.imdbId = parsedObj['imdb_id'];
    };
    movieReq.open('GET', 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/299537?api_key=34f8307d9addabf7924eab7f22cabb23', false);
    movieReq.send();
}

When using console.log to return the responseText, this is the result:
```

{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/w2PMyoyLU22YvrGK3smVM9fW1jj.jpg","belongs_to_collection":null,"budget":152000000,"genres":[{"id":28,"name":"Action"},{"id":12,"name":"Adventure"},{"id":878,"name":"Science Fiction"}],"homepage":"https://www.marvel.com/movies/captain-marvel","id":299537,"imdb_id":"tt4154664","original_language":"en","original_title":"Captain Marvel","overview":"The story follows Carol Danvers as she becomes one of the universe’s most powerful heroes when Earth is caught in the middle of a galactic war between two alien races. Set in the 1990s, Captain Marvel is an all-new adventure from a previously unseen period in the history of the Marvel Cinematic Universe.","popularity":419.096,"poster_path":"/AtsgWhDnHTq68L0lLsUrCnM7TjG.jpg","production_companies":[{"id":420,"logo_path":"/hUzeosd33nzE5MCNsZxCGEKTXaQ.png","name":"Marvel Studios","origin_country":"US"}],"production_countries":[{"iso_3166_1":"US","name":"United States of America"}],"release_date":"2019-03-06","revenue":910298835,"runtime":124,"spoken_languages":[{"iso_639_1":"en","name":"English"}],"status":"Released","tagline":"Higher. Further. Faster.","title":"Captain Marvel","video":false,"vote_average":7.3,"vote_count":2885}

Comment: It's valid JSON - try placing it in https://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had forgotten to add a check for the onreadystatechange event. I added the following check and ran the json parse within the if statement and this fixed my issue!

```
movieReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var parsedObj = JSON.parse(movieReq.responseText);
        mO.imdbId = parsedObj['imdb_id'];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question when you return 
`console.log(movieReq.responseText)`
above the line:

`var parsedObj = JSON.parse(movieReq.responseText);`

You get the correct JSON, right?

If so, it means you don't need to use the function JSON.parse(), you can access any element of the object movieReq.responseText directly, in your case you could access `movieReq.responseText.imdb_id` without the need to parse it (because it is a JSON object already).

You only need to use JSON.parse() if you want to convert a string to a JSON object, for more information please check: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: The response from the server is json data in text format. I updated my post to add what fixed my issue.